# Void menu module not works

Tags: 7

I installed the [Void menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/void_menu) module and I created a link in the main menu with the Path field set to `<void>`.

When I click in the menu item, the href is `javascript%3A%20void%280%29%3B` instead of `javascript: void(0);`

Any idea for fix this issue?

Comment: By me it works fine.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1698542 ? What other modules are you using which alter menu output (e.g. Superfish, Menu Block, etc)?